# How to reduce a pair RDD by filtering out given set of keys?

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark

I have a pair RDD of the format: `RDD[(String, String)]` and list of keys from a file. I want have an RDD which contains only those key-value pairs that matches the key from the list. How can I achieve this (in Scala, preferably)? 
Thank you.

Comment: Is the list of allowed key very large?

Comment: No. It's an 8-digit key in the list.

Comment: It wasn't about size of each key, but about whole dataset of keys. If it's small, then you can simply use broadcast variable. If not, then you should consider joining two datasets or RDDs. In my answer I've posted both version

Comment: The size of the list is quite small. So, I'll go with broadcasting approach. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok :) I will keep part with large dataset, maybe someone else will use it later :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how many data do you have.

## Small dataset (can be broadcasted)

Use broadcast variable to send list to each executor, then filter using variable:

```
val allowedSet = Source.fromFile("filename.txt").getLines.toSet
val allowedBV = sparkContext.broadcast(allowedSet)

val filtered = pairRDD.filter (x => allowedBV.value.contains(x._1))
```

## Large dataset

I don't see any easy method of joining not-pair RDDs, but you can use Dataset:

```
val allowedDS = sc.parallelize(allowedSet).toDF("allowedKey").as[String]
```

Then join your Dataset with this Dataset:

```
val joined = pairRDD.toDF("key", "value").join (allowedDS, 'key === 'allowedKey).dropColumn('allowedKey);
```

Alternatively you can do cartesian of these two RDDs, but it can be very slow

Comment: Thanks a lot for the variety of options you suggested. I have tried broadcasting approach and it's working.

Comment: What if I have an `RDD[String]` instead of `Set[String]`? How to filter those strings from incoming RDD?

Answer (score 4):

I guess you may use `RDD.filter`:

```
rdd.filter(yourKeysList.contains(_._1))
```

[Here](http://backtobazics.com/big-data/spark/apache-spark-filter-example/) are some more descriptive examples for doing filtration with Scala or Python.

Answer (score 1):

Actually quite easy:

```
import scala.io.Source
val inclusions = Source.fromFile("filename.txt").getLines.toSet

yourRDD.filter(t => inclusions.contains(t._1))
```

that's it.

Comment: This is an extremely inefficient implementation.  You should use a set instead, and probably broadcast it so it's only transmitted once to each executor JVM

Comment: true - a set is much better and broadcast also makes sense